# Reading from arduino's serial port using go-serial

Tags: python, go, arduino, serial-port

I have arduino uno with simple firmware which provides simple API over serial port:

- Command "read" returns the current state
- Command "on" sets the state to "on"
- Command "off" sets the state to "off"

Now I want to implement a client for this device.
If I use Arduino IDE serial monitor, this API works as expected.
If I use python with pySerial library, API works.

But whenever I try to read data from the serial port using golang and go-serial, my read calls hangs (but works fine with /dev/pts/X created by socat, for example)

Python client

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0")
s.write("read\n")
resp = []
char = None
while char != "\r":
    char = s.read()
    resp.append(char)
print "".join(resp)
```

Go client (hangs on Read call forever):
    package main

```
import "fmt"
import "github.com/jacobsa/go-serial/serial"

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {
    options := serial.OpenOptions{
        PortName:        "/dev/ttyACM0",
        BaudRate:        19200,
        DataBits:        8,
        StopBits:        1,
        MinimumReadSize: 4,
    }
    port, err := serial.Open(options)
    check(err)
    n, err := port.Write([]byte("read\n"))
    check(err)
    fmt.Println("Written", n)
    buf := make([]byte, 100)
    n, err = port.Read(buf)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println("Readen", n)
    fmt.Println(string(buf))
}
```

Firmware code:

```
String inputString = "";         // a String to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete
String state = "off";

void setup() {
    // initialize serial:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
    inputString.reserve(200);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // print the string when a newline arrives:
    if (stringComplete) {
        blink();
        if (inputString == "on\n") {
        state = "on";  
        } else if (inputString == "off\n") {
        state = "off";  
        } else if (inputString == "read\n") {
        Serial.println(state  );  
        }
        // clear the string:
        inputString = "";
        stringComplete = false;
    }
}


void blink() {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // set the LED on
    delay(1000);              // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // set the LED off
    delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}

void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
        // get the new byte:
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
        // add it to the inputString:
        inputString += inChar;
        // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
        // do something about it:
        if (inChar == '\n') {
        stringComplete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Python code

Comment: My only guess: You've set a minimum read size of 4.  If there are fewer than 4 bytes read, will it block?

Comment: Serial.println() equal to on python `ser.readline()` (so your delimiter is `\n`) another point is : C++ and python  no diference, like ` while (Serial.available())(ardu) == while True: while ser.inWaiting() > 0: (python)`

Comment: @dsgdfg yes, I could replace this code with ser.readline(), without while loop, but my intend is to have golang version working, python code is for example, that device is working at all.

Comment: @Flimzy I have tried with minimum size equals 1, still nothing.

Comment: `"/dev/ttyACM0"` and `"/dev/ttyACM1"` **I hope it's a joke.**

Comment: @dsgdfg execuse me? I have different ports from time to time. The PID:VID doesn't binded to some particular tty device and the number assigned differs from time to time. Once I plug it in, it would be ACM1, another time it would be ACM0. UPD: I will update the question to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the baud rate for the Go lang function to 19200, but in the arduino you have used 9600.

In the python code, the baud rate is not set, so it takes the default of 9600.

Just set the right baud rate in your go lang program, and it should work.

Comment: No, it has no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: Try with 19200 and then 9600, confirm if the Arduino blinks or not.
This will tell you if the Arduino gets the command in the first place or not.

Comment: arudino blinked with both variants.

Comment: However, I remade arduino code a bit, using Serial.readString for reading and now everyhting works, if I set vmin\vtime in golang version.